# Monitor and automatically restart a process

Tags: macos, filemaker

I have a Mac Pro running OS X 10.9 with FileMaker Server (FMS) installed. One of the processes running is `fmsased` (script execution daemon). Periodically this crashes and I have to log into and restart it from the command line (`fmsadmin restart fmse -y`).

Is there a way of monitoring that process and if it fails automatically issuing the command line instruction?

I've looked at Lingon but couldn't figure out how to do this with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The plissé file for launchd is described here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html

Answer (score 1):

Lingon is a GUI to `launchd` command line utility that manages OS X processes that run in the background.

Basically,  to have `launchd` manage your FileMaker server, all you need to do is to create a special XML file called a property list (.plist) and place it an appropriate place.

[Here](http://launchd.info) is a nice (and easy) explanation of how it works and how to configure it.